# How to mix different fonts in the same paragraph with pdfkit in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, pdfkit

as you can see every paragraph is in bold, I wanted only the ${item} variable to be in bold and the rest with another font

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmwQR.png

my code:

doc.fontSize(20).text(`Certifico para os devidos fins que ${item}`, 20, 248);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`` doc.fontSize(20).text(`Certifico para os devidos fins que ${item}`, 20, 248); ``

To draw text with multiple styles we can split the text where text style changes and measure width of that text and add as left to the next text to be drawn. In your case **${item}** text needs bold.

```
doc.fontSize(20).text(`Certifico para os devidos fins que ${item}`, 20, 248);
var textWidth = doc.widthOfString('Certifico para os devidos fins que ');
//Add your new text style here
doc.text(`${item}`, 20 + textWidth, 248);
```